# PID controller implementation in Python

Tags: pid-controller, python

I'm trying to implement a PID controller for a magnetic field using Python.

The magnetic field needs to be around 800µT.  It is generated by two coils powered by a current source (BKprecision XLN3640.) I measure the magnetic field with a three axis sensor (Bartington Mag-03.) Both of them are connected to the computer over USB.

I read *PID without a PhD* and https://github.com/pms67/PID to code the PID.

Here is my code:

```py
from cmath import inf
import time

class PID:
    """
    Implements a PID controller.
    """

    def __init__(self, Kp: float, Ki: float, Kd: float, target: float, tau: float) -> None:
        """

        Parameters
        ----------
        Kp : float
            Proportional gain.
        Ki : float
            Integration gain.
        Kd : float
            Derivative gain.
        tau : float
            Low pass filter time constant.
        target : float
            Target value.
        """
        
        self.Kp = Kp
        self.Ki = Ki
        self.Kd = Kd
        self.tau = tau
        self.target = target
        self.Dterm = 0
        self.Iterm = 0
        self.last_error = 0
        self.last_time = time.time()
        self.last_feedback = 0
        self.last_output = 0
        self.set_limits(0, inf, -inf, inf)

    def set_limits(self, min: float, max: float, min_int: float, max_int: float) -> None:
        """
        Output limits.

        Parameters
        ----------
        min : float
            Minimum output.
        max : float
            Maximum output.
        """
        self.max = max
        self.max_int = max_int
        self.min = min
        self.min_int = min_int

    def update(self, feedback: float) -> float:
        """
        Calculate the PID output value.

        Parameters
        ----------
        feedback : float
            Value to be compared to the target.

        Returns
        -------
        float
            Output of the PID controller.
        """
        error = self.target - feedback
        
        current_time = time.time()
        delta_time = 0.001
        if delta_time == 0:
            return self.last_output

        self.Pterm = self.Kp * error
        self.Iterm += (error + self.last_error) * 0.5 * self.Ki * delta_time
        self.Dterm = (-2 * self.Kd * (feedback - self.last_feedback)
                      + (2 * self.tau - delta_time) * self.Dterm / (2 * self.tau + delta_time))

        if self.Iterm > self.max_int:
            self.Iterm = self.max_int
        elif self.Iterm < self.min_int:
            self.Iterm = self.min_int

        self.last_time = current_time
        self.last_error = error
        self.last_feedback = feedback

        print(f"P: {self.Pterm}, I: {self.Iterm}, f: {feedback}")

        output = self.Pterm + self.Iterm + self.Dterm
        if output < self.min:
            return self.min
        if output > self.max:
            return self.max
        self.last_output = output
        return output
```

My problem is when setting the constants Kp, Ki and Kd. I'm not getting the results I expected.

When I use only a PI controller with `Kp=1e4` and `Ki=7e4` the controller works but it has a strange behavior. When it reaches the target value, the field slowly decreases and then jumps over the target. Any idea why it behaves like this?

[image: PI controller response]

I then tried to follow the method given in *PID without a PhD* but it resulted in very unstable controller. It says Ki must be smaller than Kp that must be smaller than Kd but I need to do the opposite to get stability.

I am also wondering about sampling time. The example above is without sampling time control. The loop just goes as fast as possible and the delta time is calculated with `time.time()`. I then was wondering if fixed sampling time was better. I tried a sampling time of 1ms. The controller was very slow to reach the target. It the gives the results I want but I need to have a faster response for the system.

[image: Fixed sampling time]

The magnetic field response is almost instantaneous when current is changed. Does a PID controller correspond to that situation?

Do you have any other advice about my PID controller?

Comment: Constant sampling is required. What computer are you using? A non real-time OS such as Windows will make this difficult.

Comment: FYI, the author of *PID without a PhD* is a contributer here, he may help.

Comment: Why is constant sampling required ? I am using Windows and I can't use any other OS because drivers for the field measurement are only available on Windows. I already spent two weeks to understand how this closed source software works...

Comment: `delta_time = 0.001` You're not calculating the actual delay, or is this the wrong revision of the code?

Comment: But even if you do use `delta_time = time.time() - self.last_time` the program can be "briefly" interrupted at any moment causing occasional errors.

Comment: Yes, I was using `delta_time = time.time() - self.last_time`. So it's not possible to create a PID controller on Windows ? Is there any other solution to stabilize the field from the computer ?

Comment: It will never work reliably on any non-realtime operating system.  But you can probably improve things by setting a process affinity on Windows to avoid having the process jumping between CPUs.  // And I /think/ the OS MIGHT be even kinder if you run the code on a repeated timer instead of continuously. (Ie. the OS will be told when you want the code to run and it will only run for a short amount of time each iteration.)

Comment: Even if you do run it on a repeated timer, I would still suggest measuring the delay between iterations. Because if it is much longer than anticipated, D-regulation will think the process is changing rapidly while in reality it's changing only very slowly.

Comment: What do you mean by running the code on a repeated timer ? How can I achieve that ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/138059/discussion-between-oskar-skog-and-louisld).

Answer (score 1):

delta time is time between two samples ie current - previous time between two code executions. If you are running on pc you will not get best results due to non real time nature of pc os as others have pointed out. Try to change priority of process to get better results.